# How to manually resolve dependecies from different class?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

For now i've resolved module in a entry point of application and it works good.
Bit i've problem with resolving dependicies in provided/exported module.
I just putin:

```
providers: [..., { provide: ConsumerClass, useClass: ConsumerClass }],
exports: [..., { provide: ConsumerClass, useClass: ConsumerClass }]
```

in constructor of ConsumerClass i've one property, like

```
constructor(private readonly service: CustomService)
```

and this property always undefined. What i need to do? How i can manually resolve dependecies?

Comment: You should just export the token `ConsumerClass` instead of  `{ provide: ConsumerClass, useClass: ConsumerClass }`.